# I am trying to update a table on joining them in order to give 2% bonus to the person who hasn't received at all

Tags: oracle, sql-update, left-join

2 tables employee_1 and bonus_1 joined and trying to update but gives me the error -

```
ERROR REPORT UNKNOWN COMMAND
```

```sql
UPDATE(
  SELECT e.first_name,
         sum(b.bonus_amount) as bon
  from   employee_1 e
         LEFT join bonus_1 b
         on e.employee_id=b.employee_id
  group by e.first_name
)
set bon=0.2*e.salary
where bon IS NULL;
```

Please help me update this join query to give 2% bonus to employees whose bonus amount will be null in `bonus_amount`.

Comment: The SQL command is not valid.   You can not UPDATE a [query], you must update a table.

Comment: Then only way is to make this join statement as a new table and then  update it?

Comment: No, you must UPDATE employee_1  SET [some value] WHERE [some condition]

Comment: @BretWeinraub If the OP wants to add a bonus then they would want to `INSERT` into the `bonus_1` table (rather than an `UPDATE` of the base salary as that would be a pay-rise and not a bonus).

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you posted sample data.

With tables I imagine you have:

```
SQL> select * from employee_1;

EMPLOYEE_ID     SALARY
----------- ----------
          1        100
          2        200

SQL> select * From bonus_1;

EMPLOYEE_ID BONUS_AMOUNT
----------- ------------
          1           20
          2       --> no bonus for this employee, so their salary should be raised by 2%
```

One option might be `merge`:

```
SQL> merge into employee_1 e
  2    using (select b.employee_id,
  3                  sum(b.bonus_amount) as bon
  4           from bonus_1 b
  5           group by b.employee_id
  6          ) x
  7    on (x.employee_id = e.employee_id)
  8    when matched then update set
  9      e.salary = e.salary * 1.02
 10    where x.bon is null;

1 row merged.

SQL> select * from employee_1;

EMPLOYEE_ID     SALARY
----------- ----------
          1        100
          2        204
```

Another might be `updat`e:

```
SQL> rollback;

Rollback complete.

SQL> merge into employee_1 e
  2    using (select b.employee_id,
  3                  sum(b.bonus_amount) as bon
  4           from bonus_1 b
  5           group by b.employee_id
  6          ) x
  7    on (x.employee_id = e.employee_id)
  8    when matched then update set
  9      e.salary = e.salary * 1.02
 10    where x.bon is null;

1 row merged.

SQL> select * From employee_1;

EMPLOYEE_ID     SALARY
----------- ----------
          1        100
          2        204

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer but 1 small change I want it to only reflect in bonus_AMOUNT IN BONUS AND NOT IN EMPLOYEE_1

Comment: You're welcome. As I said, it would really help if you posted sample data and desired result. Because, if you don't, we still have to *imagine* what you really have. I tried and failed; don't feel like trying again. Therefore, please, post sample data.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to **display** the amount then do not use `UPDATE`, just use `SELECT` and `COALESCE`:

```sql
SELECT MAX(e.first_name) AS first_name,
       COALESCE(
         SUM(b.bonus_amount),
         0.2*MAX(e.salary)
       ) as bon
FROM   employee_1 e
       LEFT JOIN bonus_1 b
       ON e.employee_id=b.employee_id
GROUP BY e.employee_id;
```

*Note: do not `GROUP BY e.first_name` as you will aggregate together people with the same first name; which is almost certainly incorrect.*

---

If you want to modify the `bonus_1` table to add a bonus when there are no bonuses for an employee then you want an `INSERT` statement and not an `UPDATE`:

```sql
INSERT INTO bonus_1 (employee_id, bonus_amount)
SELECT employee_id, 0.2*salary
FROM   employee_1 e
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM bonus_1 b WHERE b.employee_id = e.employee_id);
```

Or a `MERGE ... WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT ...` statement:

```sql
MERGE INTO bonus_1 b
USING employee_1 e
ON (b.employee_id = e.employee_id)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (employee_id, bonus_amount)
  VALUES (e.employee_id, 0.2*e.salary);
```

*Note: your title states a 2% bonus, if that is the case then 0.02 = 2% whereas 0.2 = 20%.*

Once you have performed the insert then:

```sql
SELECT MAX(e.first_name) AS first_name,
       sum(b.bonus_amount) as bon
FROM   employee_1 e
       LEFT JOIN bonus_1 b
       ON e.employee_id=b.employee_id
GROUP BY e.employee_id;
```

Will have a row for all employees to **display** the bonuses.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/YAVDjtMy)